# How can I set the initial content/value of this tinymce?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tinymce, vuetify.js

I am using this tinymce editor in my application: https://github.com/dyonir/vue-tinymce-editor.

I want to fill my editor with content when initialized.

I have tried v-model.

```
<tinymce id="d1" v-model="hello"></tinymce>
```

---

```
data(){
 return {
  hello: 'hello'
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project you reference has not been updated in a long time.  TinyMCE itself has an official Vue wrapper that they actively maintain:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue

Have you tried using that integration code instead?  If the other code works (or you can get an answer from its developer) there is no reason you can't use that code but the Git Issue tracker looks fairly unattended.

Note: *For full disclosure I work for the company that makes TinyMCE (and the Vue wrapper I linked to above).*

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.